# Using a public void from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net

Hey guys so i have a public void methode that loads table in gridview in a form i want to access that methode when closing a second form and comming back to the one with the methode any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question should be [mcve]. Please see this [ask] good question.

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of FormClosed/FormClosing event of the second form. When the second form closes, the event handler in the first form will be invoked and you could call the public method there.

Example:

```
public partial class FirstForm : Form
{
    public void OpenSecondForm()
    {
        SecondForm form = new SecondForm();
        form.FormClosed += SecondForm_FormClosed;

        form.Show();
    }

    private void SecondForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PopulateGridView();
    }

    public void PopulateGridView()
    {
    }
}
```